# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X1_{\{X>n\}}=0 \space\space\space\text{a.s.}$

Tags: probability-theory

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X1_{\{X>n\}}=0 \space\space\space\text{a.s.}$$

This is a claim I need to use in part of a proof that involves the dominated convergence theorem.

Since it holds almost surely, I need to show that $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X1_{X>n}=0)=1$

$$\forall\varepsilon > 0,\exists N \text{ s.t. }\forall n\ge N,P(|X1_{X>n}|\ge\varepsilon)=0$$

Rewriting,

$$P(|X1_{X>n}|\ge 2^{-n})=0$$

Do I have to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that if $X$ is a random variable, then $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ . In particular, $X(\omega)$ is finite for every $\omega$. Now, fix an $\omega\in\Omega$ and pick a natural number $N(\omega)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N(\omega)\geq X(\omega)$, e.g. $N(\omega)=\lceil X(\omega)\rceil$ where $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ denotes the ceiling function. Then
$$
\mathbf{1}_{\{X>n\}}(\omega)=\mathbf{1}_{\{X(\omega)>n\}}=0,\quad \text{for all }n\geq N(\omega).
$$
In particular, 
$$
X(\omega)\mathbf{1}_{\{X>n\}}(\omega)\to 0\quad\text{for }n\to\infty.
$$
Since $\omega$ was arbitrary, we conclude that
$$
\left\{\omega\;\Big|\;\lim_{n\to\infty} X(\omega)\mathbf{1}_{\{X>n\}}(\omega)=0\right\}=\Omega.
$$